# Проблемы с кодировкой. Строки на английском языка принимаются нормально

Tags: objective-c, xcode, utf-8

Есть код:

```
- (void)readFromStreamToInputBuffer {
    uint8_t buffer[4096];

    while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
        NSInteger bytesRead = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
        [inputBuffer appendBytes:buffer length:bytesRead];
    }

    [self parseIncomingData];
}

- (void)parseIncomingData {
    while ([inputBuffer length] > 0) {
        NSString* bufferString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy: [inputBuffer mutableBytes] length:[inputBuffer length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding freeWhenDone: NO];

        NSRange rangeDelim = [bufferString rangeOfString: messageDelimiter];

        if (rangeDelim.location == NSNotFound)
            break;

        NSString* message = [bufferString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, rangeDelim.location)];
        if (messageReceivedBlock != nil) {
            messageReceivedBlock(self,message);
        }

    [inputBuffer replaceBytesInRange: NSMakeRange(0, rangeDelim.location + rangeDelim.length)
                           withBytes: NULL
                              length: 0];
  }
}
```

Строки на английском языка принимаются нормально, но вот на русском принимаются крякозябры. Думаю, проблема с кодировкой, принимать нужно в utf8 вставлял `NSUTF8StringEncoding` закрывается с исключением.

Comment: Поподробнее про исключение, пожалуйста.

Comment: 2013-12-10 15:03:03.512 qqqq[2926:70b] Response : (null)
2013-12-10 15:03:03.514 qqqq[2926:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderMutableString initWithString:]: nil argument'